# How to write a get api to obtain employee hierarchy till CEO for a specific employee

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, get

I want to write an api To get entire manager hierarchy for an employee upto CEO
For example in below table-

```
EmployeeName    ManagerName
C                 D
B                 C
G                 C
E                 B
F                 B
A                 B
D                 NULL
```

For employee A I want the output as BCD

I'm using ASP.NET Core Web API, SQL Server for the same.

I've tried writing code as-

```
[Route("empLevel/{id}")]
        public IActionResult GetEmpHierarchy(int id)
        {
           List<Employee> emp = entity.Employees.ToList();
           List<Employee> mngr = entity.Employees.ToList();

            var query = (from e in emp
                         join m in mngr on e.MngId equals m.Id
                         select new Employee { Id = e.Id, MngId = m.MngId }).Where(x => x.Id == id).ToList();

            return Ok(query);
        }
```

But still result is not as expected. Please provide a solution.

Comment: Try putting the where clause inside the from statement

Answer (score 0):

You need a recursion operation for navigating from current position to top level. Also, you can implement the solution using a `while-loop` and replacing the current node each time.

To write code it is needed to know how employees/managers are linked to others which in this case seems to be `MngId`.